# What are $r(s)$ and $\theta(s)$ for an ellipse?

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry, vector-analysis, curves

Book:
[https://www.amazon.com/Vector-Calculus-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486466205](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486466205)

We have this problem here on page 89.

[image: pic1]

I think I was able to solve a) and c).

I know that b) is an ellipse. And I think we can also assume that the parameters $a,b$ are positive.

But for b) I don't know how to present the parametrization in the form

$$\boldsymbol{r}(s) = r(s) \cdot (\cos{(\theta(s))}, \sin{(\theta(s))}) \tag{*}$$

where $r,\theta$ are scalar functions.

This presentation is needed in order to apply the formulas given in the text.

I think this makes b) much harder than a) and c).
I think also that there might be some theory here which I am missing.
Or maybe the problem was meant to be just for the case $a=b$?!

Any ideas or hints?

**EDIT:** Radial and transverse components refer to the representations of $\boldsymbol{\dot{r}(s)}$ and $\boldsymbol{\ddot{r}(s)}$ as linear combinations of these two vectors.

$\boldsymbol{\hat{r}}(s) = (\cos{(\theta(s))}, \sin{(\theta(s))})$
$\boldsymbol{\hat{s}}(s) = (-\sin{(\theta(s))}, \cos{(\theta(s))})$

Also, $s$ is just some parameter, not necessarily path-length.

More details here:

[image: pic2]

Comment: Can you please edit the question to clarify whether "radial" and "transverse" refer to (i) normal and tangential components relative to the curve's own Frenet frame; (ii) to components relative to standard polar coordinates; or (iii) something else? <> If $s$ denotes an arc length parameter, briefly "you can't" write the ellipse in the requested form except by inverting an elliptic integral, so probably you'll need something beyond the book's formulas. Exactly what you need, however, depends on the meanings of radial and transverse.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang OK. Done. Also, $s$ is not a path-length parameter, just some parameter. I put $s$ just so that it differs from the parameter $t$. But it could be $u$ or $p$ or whatever.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! <> Parts (i) through (iii) are OK, right? For (iv), note that at the point $(x, y)$ in Cartesian coordinates, the radial and transverse components are dot products with the unit vectors$$r = \frac{(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\qquad s = \frac{(-y,x)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.$$Please feel free to write up your own answer!

Answer (score 0):

- To avoid ambiguity, try using polar coordinates:

\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{r} &= r \, \hat{r} \\
  \mathbf{v} &= \dot{r} \, \hat{r}+r\dot{\theta} \, \hat{\theta} \\
  \mathbf{a} &= (\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2) \, \hat{r}+
                (2\dot{r}\dot{\theta}+r\ddot{\theta}) \, \hat{\theta}
\end{align*}

- In the language of differential geometry, $s$ is the arclength, $\kappa$ is the curvature and $\rho$ is the radius of curvature.  Acceleration will include the tangential component (along $\mathbf{T}$) and normal component (along $\mathbf{N}$) which is the centripetal acceleration but is given by radius of curvature instead.

\begin{align}
  \mathbf{v} &= \dot{s} \, \mathbf{T} \\
  &= v \, \mathbf{T} \\
  \mathbf{a} &= \ddot{s} \, \mathbf{T}+ \kappa \, \dot{s}^2\mathbf{N} \\
  &= \frac{d^2s}{dt^2} \mathbf{T} + \frac{v^2}{\rho} \mathbf{N} \\
  &= v\frac{dv}{ds} \mathbf{T} + \frac{v^2}{\rho} \mathbf{N} \\
\end{align}

- Please also refer to my answer in **Physics SE** [*here*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/379471/expression-for-the-centripetal-acceleration/379520#379520).
- Back to your problem, it's just a simple exercise of calculus

\begin{align}
  \mathbf{r} &= (a\cos \omega t,b\sin \omega t) \\
  \mathbf{v} &= \omega \, (-a\sin \omega t,b\cos \omega t) \\
  v &= \omega \sqrt{a^2\sin^2 \omega t+b^2\cos^2 \omega t} \\
  \mathbf{a} &= -\omega^2 \mathbf{r}
\end{align}